# NoSQL Technology for High Throughput Insert

Tags: database, nosql

Out of the no-sql technologies out there, which one is better suited for high throughput inserts? I am sure this depends on hardware too but let's assume I am using amazon cluster compute node with fixed step and ideally want the least number of nodes. I need a storage system than can deliver 20GB/min inserts where my data is fully structured and each row is about 110bytes. **Theoretically**, I can increase my hardware indefinably to achieve  this  but I am wondering which technology is better suited for this high throughput inserts?

Answer (score 1):

You want to be looking at the fully-distributed data sources like HBase, Cassandra, MongoDB, etc.  A sharded MySQL or other relational database could also work, assuming you have enough shards.  So in summary, you probably don't want to base your decision on just this one criteria.

Answer (score 0):

*thinking out loud*

- In simple terms => "20GB/min" is "350MB/s" so that definitely requires either 10Gbit NIC, in case it is over the network, and lots of cache, hence RAM.
- Given the rate and a (small) message size you probably would not want to deal with GC, although paid for solutions (e.g. Azul) might be able to sustain it.
- "*ideally want the least number of nodes*" => that means a traditional horizontal scaling NoSQLs are out, unless a 100+ nodes can be considered as "the least"
- Does it need to be NoSQL? What is the *actual problem* at hand? Is this a batch job (acceptable high latency)? Is it a market feed (e.g. a peak for *some* time)? Is it a school project?
- Since you think of using Amazon, and *do* want to do NoSQL, DynamoDB would be worth trying as it "guarantees" the required throughput